# How do I enter a string in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Suppose we're on a webpage that has a textbox for input with the CSS path `input[type = 'input']`.

I'm trying to write a script that runs on Chrome+Tampermonkey that will enter a text in this textbox and then press on the 'apply' button.

For the 'apply' button something like this will work:

```
function To3(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    'use strict';
     $( "button[label='apply']" ).click()
     To1();
  }, 2000);
}
```

How can I write a script that will enter a text in the above textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like `input[type="text"]`, right? Not `input[type="input"]`.

I believe your question is how to set an input value in jQuery using a selector. If so, the answer is:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val(yourValue)
```

[Check the .val() reference](http://api.jquery.com/val/).